# Syntax error using def on python

Tags: python, syntax-error, function

My qestion is that my def kept on getting a invalid syntax.

```
l=0
a=1
b=1
i=int(input("How many iterations?" )

def mains():
    while i>l; 
        l=l+1
        a=a+b
        print(a)

def mains()
```

Here is the error.

```
  File "Fibonacci.py", line 6
    def mains():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am currently using 3.4.1 version of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly you have incomplete `)` on the previous line:

```
i=int(input("How many iterations?" ))
                                    ^
```

and secondly, it should be `:` not `;`:

```
while i>l:
```

and thirdly, to call a method, you just do:

```
mains()
```

not `def mains()`